# Ускорить if проверку или уменьшить код

Tags: php, if

Добрый день!

Приходиться делать вот такую, громоздкую проверку массива:

```
if ($service['is_annulated'] == '1') {
    if ($service['type_id'] == 'Билеты' || $service['type_id'] == 'БилетыЖД') {
        $service['status'] = 'is_annulated';
    } else {
        $service['status'] = 'is_annulated_request';
    }
} 
else {
    if ($service['type_id'] == 'БилетыЖД' || $service['type_id'] == 'Билеты') {
        $service['status'] = 'tickets';
    } else {
        if ($service['is_garant'] == '1') {
            if ($today >> $service['annulation_date']) {
                $service['status'] = 'warning';
            } else {
                $service['status'] = 'live';
            }
        } else {
            if ($today >> $service['annulation_date']) {
                $service['status'] = 'failed';
            } else {
                $service['status'] = 'live';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е. проверяем по 4-ем параметрам, которые не имеют линейной зависимости.
Заметил, что скорость выполнения функции, куда входит эта шняга, выросла почти в два раза.

Можно ли как-либо боком заставить все это дело работать быстрее?

p.s. PHP 5.3 и апгрейдить нельзя.

p.p.s самописный движок

Comment: Вы уверены, что тормозит именно этот код?

Comment: И кстати, вот здесь `if ($today >> $service['annulation_date']) {` ошибки нет? Вам нужен именно побитовый сдвиг?

Comment: Побитовый сдвиг, это как? (да-да, я неуч) Ну тащем-то, тормозить стало, когда с утра пришлось сделать эту проверку, и если это тупо закоментировать - то работает на порядок бодрее.

Comment: для начала декомпозировать

Comment: Сравнение, конечно. Написано много, но дважды одно проверять не будет. Надо некоторые проверки записать в булевы переменные, но особенно разницы не будет.

Comment: @DantheHat, замените `>>` на `>` чтобы было сравнение `сегодняшняя дата больше той даты` :)

Comment: Если сравнение, то это >. Побитовый сдвиг умножает на 2 столько раз, сколько в той переменной число.

Comment: @DantheHat `if (10 > 8)` даст true, а `if (10 >> 8)` даст false. Что Вы пытаетесь проверить условием `if ($today >> $service['annulation_date']) {`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov разницу между сегодня и датой аннуляции, ну т.е. если сегодня больше даты аннуляции - то все, капец.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d4340388c9fe28aa29e32079da7d8c5bd61ccbb  - примерно как можно уменьшить.... и даже еще можно.... но тормозить данный код не должен в принципе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Спасибо) Все никак не освоюсь с таким написанием if-ов

Comment: еще чуть более менее http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d45b07802d485ecdca1ab3cab8ef1410a5c91cfc  .......... но это только в теории.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov спасибо, с одинарной галочкой стало пошустрее работать.

Comment: то есть по сути проблема, как я понимаю, была в побитовом сдвиге :D

Comment: ну судя по всему - да, надо пойти почитать на эту тему, ибо на неком подсознательном уровне всегда в сравнениях ставил двойные галочки =\

Comment: Что тут читать, > Есть больше, + плюс - минус.